# Can't see a directory that's supposed to exist

Tags: debian, command-line, raspberry-pi, cd-command, bitcoin

So I own a device (casa node) which is basically a raspberry pi 3b+ with a hard drive and a modified OS (they call it CasaOS) and I want to edit a file. I found the location of this file by looking at the debug logs of the program that uses it. here's what they look like:

```
2019-01-05T22:11:44Z Bitcoin Core version v0.17.0 (release build)
2019-01-05T22:11:44Z InitParameterInteraction: parameter interaction: -whitelistforcerelay=1 -> setting -whitelistrel$2019-01-05T22:11:44Z Assuming ancestors of block 0000000000000000002e63058c023a9a1de233554f28c7b21380b6c9003f36a8 hav$2019-01-05T22:11:44Z Setting nMinimumChainWork=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000028822fef1c230963535a90d
2019-01-05T22:11:44Z Using the 'standard' SHA256 implementation
2019-01-05T22:11:44Z Default data directory /root/.bitcoin
2019-01-05T22:11:44Z Using data directory /usr/local/casa/chains/bitcoind/data/
2019-01-05T22:11:44Z Using config file /usr/local/casa/chains/bitcoind/conf/bitcoin.conf
```

The `bitcoin.conf` is the on I'm after, however I can't get in the directory. Once I'm in `/usr/local/casa`  I can't see or `cd` into the `chains` dir. the `ls -a` command returns

```
.  ..  applications  launch.sh
```

How can I get in the chains folder and ultimately to the `bitcoin.conf` file? I did all of this as root.

Comment: Is the application chrooted? I.e. does it have a displaced root directory under which the path exists?  What's, for example, under `/root/.bitcoin/usr/local/...`?

Comment: K7AAY, if you mean sudo ls -a, then it returns the same thing.   Kusalananda, I have no idea how to check that. Does that help?  root@casa-node:/usr/local/casa# ls -al
total 16
drwxr-sr-x  3 root staff 4096 Dec  5 16:30 .
drwxrwsr-x 11 root staff 4096 Nov 14 01:50 ..
drwxr-sr-x  2 root staff 4096 Apr  2 14:54 applications
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   321 Apr  4 12:53 launch.sh

Comment: You might try to use find: find / -name bitcoin.conf

Comment: Oh my God Fitz, you are literally the best. Thanks. The actual path was `/mnt/data/overlay2/60fe75e985602eb59c95fb97c0002750e4a41935c02a9d73472b8997f52a879e/diff/usr/local/casa/chains/bitcoind/conf/bitcoin.conf` I would have never found it myself if it wasn't for you! Thanks to the others for the great tips and effort too!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is made from the comments of Fitz and the Questioner:

To find the file:

```
find / -name bitcoin.conf
```

This shows that the file is present in:
`/mnt/data/overlay2/60fe75e985602eb59c95fb97c0002750e4a41935c02a9d73472b8997f52a879e/diff/usr/local/casa/chains/bitcoind/conf/bitcoin.conf`

Which can be mounted on a different path. Note /mnt/ is used as the default mount point for devices. You have to run these commands as `root` (prepending `sudo`)

```
umount /dev/sdx
mount /dev/sdx /usr/local/casa/chains/bitcoind
```

Or use:

```
mount -o remount, rw /dev/sdx /usr/local/casa/chains/bitcoind
```

The file can be edited as long as the device it's on is mounted, whether on default mount point `/mnt` or the path it is mounted on after the manual mounting